# libreoffice calc - find value in subtable

Tags: worksheet-function, openoffice, libreoffice, libreoffice-calc, lookup

Let's say I have a sheet and somewhere on it a table like

```
 AAAA      8      16     32     48     64
 50   x08050  x16050 x32050 x48050 x64050
150   x08150  x16150 x32150 x48150 x64150
250   x08250  x16250 x32250 x48250 x64250
350   x08350  x16350 x32350 x48350 x64350
450   x08450  x16450 x32450 x48450 x64450
550   x08550  x16550 x32550 x48550 x64550
650   x08650  x16650 x32650 x48650 x64650
```

where `xYYZZZ` represents the value in the column for `YY` and the row for `ZZZ`

How do I perform a lookup the kind of "Find me `AAAA(YY,ZZ)`"?

E.g. let's assume `AAAA` is at `I32`

then `x64650` would be at `N38`.

and say I want to lookup `x48550`

I'm looking for a way to say

> find me the value in `J32:N38` where the value on the same row in column `I` is `550` and the value on the same column in row `32` is `48`.

Comment: The row numbers do not seem correct.  If `AAAA` is in `I32`, then `x64650` should be in `N39`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Combine [MATCH](https://help.libreoffice.org/Calc/Spreadsheet_Functions#MATCH) and [VLOOKUP](https://help.libreoffice.org/Calc/Spreadsheet_Functions#VLOOKUP) as follows:

```
=VLOOKUP(550,$I$33:$N$39,MATCH(48,$J$32:$N$32)+1)
```